# How to read DB name from properties files?

Tags: python, mongodb, database-connection, pymongo, properties-file

this is my code to cocnnect to a db in mongodb, this database variable is getting dbname fro properties file now whwn I am using client.database it is not able to connect to that db but if I use client.dbname (dbname is harcoded value of DB name; it is connecting then .

I assume that p reads database name properly but when it is assigned to databse variable it converts it into string and which is why client.database is not working.

please have a look and suggest me, how I can connect to a db dynamically using database variable?

class  mongo_connection:

```
 def connectionobj(self):
     p = Properties()
     p.load(open(os.environ['MY_DATABASE']))
     database = p['spring.data.mongodb.database']
     username = p['spring.data.mongodb.username']
     password = p['spring.data.mongodb.password']
     hostname = p['spring.data.mongodb.host']
     port = p['spring.data.mongodb.port']
     url = 'mongodb://'+username+':'+password+'@'+hostname+':'+port
     #logger.info("URL for mongo connect :" + url);
     client = MongoClient(url)
     dbname = client.**database**
     #logger.info("database name  :" + url);
     id = "user"
     for i  in dbname.Login.find({"username":id}):
             print(i['username'])
     return "SUCESS"
```

m = mongo_connection()

m.connectionobj()

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
dbname = client[database]
```

Reference: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=database#module-pymongo.database